# Fleet management module in openerp7

Tags: python, python-2.7, openerp-7

I included a fuel tank capacity field in the vehicle form and also want to make litre in fuel log to be in such a way that if the litres entered while logging fuel log is more than the tank capacity of that vehicle picked it shouldn't allow it.

Here is my code, but it doesn't work:

```
def check_tank_capacity(self, cr, uid,ids, context=None):
    fleet_vehicle = self.browse(cr,uid,ids, context)[0]
    liter = fleet_vehicle.tank_capacity
    if fleet_vehicle_log_fuel.liter > fleet_vehicle.tank_capacity:
        raise osv.except_osv(('Tank Capacity!'),('Ensure that the liter you entered is not greater than the tank capacity of this vehicle'))
    return True


_constraints =[
    (check_tank_capacity, "Ensure that the liter is not greater than the tank capacity of this vehicle",['Tank Capacity'])
]
```

Comment: Could you be more specific than *"it doesn't work"*? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: A few comments about this in general, a.) you've spelt *litre* wrong in your code - which at best will just be an annoyance for anyone reading, but could lead to other people adding to the code and then you have `liter` in some places and `litre` in others. Incorrectly spelt variable names are a nuisance. and b.) you are declaring two variables and then never using them. Why?

Comment: You're also using exceptions in a nasty way, they are for "exceptional circumstances" - so here you should just return `False` and then deal with that if it happens. Ideally, the actual logging of the fuel amount would raise the relevant exception - if you have access to that.